# Problemas Entity Framework en Visual Studio c#

Tags: ado.net, framework

Hola tengo un problema al querer conectar una BD local en c#. Al momento de querer utilizar ADO.NET Entity Data Model me sale el siguiente error en una ventana de texto.
"El marco de trabajo de destino del proyecto no contiene ensamblados en tiempo de ejecución de Entity Framework. Revise la información del marco del trabajo de destino en la página de propiedades del proyecto".
Cabe mencionar que estuve cambiando el .NET que están ya instalados en la PC pero aun asi me sale el mismo error.
Espero puedan ayudarme.
Gracias.

Comment: Hola Roberto, bienvenido, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta y elimines el comentario "me urge", las preguntas con ese tipo de comentarios no "caen bien", mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Answer (score 0):

Verifique que tenga los paquetes necesarios para usar ADO, por ejemplo, los paquetes de Nuget necesarios para realizar scaffolding y conectarse a nuestra base de datos existente.

1. EntityFramework
2. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
3. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
4. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools

Posterior ejecuta:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=DESKTOP-H20O12E;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

Comment: ¡Estás en [es.so]! Las respuestas también deben estar en el idioma del sitio.